# OpenFrameworks on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspberry-pi, openframeworks, raspberry-pi2, audiovideoplayback

I had some trouble with video playback on OF (and indeed some other media libraries such as GStreamer) - specifically that it was flipped vertically and horizontally. Upon installing OF and running binaries according to examples in the excellent demonstrative tutorial [here](http://www.creativeapplications.net/tutorials/how-to-use-openframeworks-on-the-raspberrypi-tutorial/), I was disappointed to find that the examples were also behaving similarly. Is there a reason and/or way to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried OMXPlayer ? What version of OF and Raspian are you using (```uname -a```) ?

Comment: Yeah, OMXPlayer works fine of course (and there's a nice python wrapper written by willprice on github), but I was looking for a more flexible solution - specifically one that would allow multiple videos to be played on demand without destroying and recreating the player instance.
Thanks for your reply George - I suspect it may have something to do with needing to compile the source for a native build. I actually ended up switching to a Windows-based solution. It would be awesome to have some more accessible APIs for video playback on the Pi :(.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Christopher Baker's guide, it is for ARMv7 (Raspberry Pi 2)
[bakercp](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/raspberry-pi-2-setup-guide/18690)

and don't forget to run the **install_dependencies.sh**

Update: There is now a guide on the download page of oF.

Have fun !